# Different colors for annotations in google charts

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I have two types of annotations, one has links and other doesn't. I want to color them both in different colors. Is it possible?

type 1 is -
`{
    v: 'sample',
    Link: 'some link
}`

type 2 is -

`{
    v: 'sample',
}`

I want to color type1 in some color and type2 in other, is it possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can style the annotations for the overall chart,
or for each series individually

see following working snippet,
the `fontSize` is set to `10` for all annotations
then the colors are changed for the individual series

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawStacked,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawStacked() {
  var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Month', 'A', {role: 'annotation'}, 'B', {role: 'annotation'}],
    ['Aug', 3754, '3,754', 2089, '2,089'],
    ['Sept', 900, '900', 200, '200'],
    ['Oct', 2000, '2,000', 4900, '4,900'],
    ['Nov', 1700, '1,700', 2200, '2,200'],
    ['Dec', 2400, '2,400', 2089, '2,089']
  ]);

  var options = {
    annotations: {
      textStyle: {
        fontSize: 10
      }
    },
    series: {
      0: {
        annotations: {
          stem: {
            color: 'cyan',
            length: 5
          },
          textStyle: {
            color: 'cyan'
          }
        }
      },
      1: {
        annotations: {
          stem: {
            color: 'magenta',
            length: 10
          },
          textStyle: {
            color: 'magenta'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

**EDIT**

to have different colors for annotations in a single series,
need to change color manually when the `'ready'` event fires

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawStacked,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawStacked() {
  var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Month', 'A', {role: 'annotation'}],
    ['Aug', 3754, '3,754'],
    ['Sept', {v: 900, p: {link: 'type A'}}, '900'],
    ['Oct', {v: 2000, p: {link: 'type B'}}, '2,000'],
    ['Nov', 1700, '1,700'],
    ['Dec', 2400, '2,400']
  ]);

  var options = {
    annotations: {
      textStyle: {
        color: '#000000',
        fontSize: 10
      }
    }
  };

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(container);

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(container.getElementsByTagName('text'), function (text, index) {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
        if ((text.getAttribute('text-anchor') === 'middle') && (text.innerHTML === data.getFormattedValue(i, 1))) {
          switch (data.getProperty(i, 1, 'link')) {
            case 'type A':
              text.setAttribute('fill', 'magenta');
              break;

            case 'type B':
              text.setAttribute('fill', 'cyan');
              break;
          }
        }
      }
    });
  });

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: hope this helps, see the [configuration options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#configuration-options) for all the settings that can be adjusted...

Comment: the problem here is that I don't have any series but jst a single bar chart