# Google Charts; Offsetting Annotations from horizontal Axis

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, charts, google-visualization

I'm looking for a way to offset the annotation labels I have on a Google Chart I'm making. I've included an image below, but essentially what I've done is created a column chart with hidden lines that the annotations are set from.

I did this because the bar type apparently doesn't support annotations. My end goal is to get the percentage of each week to display at the top of the bars. The problem is that because of the way I had to do this the percentage annotations center on the x-axis label and not on the column bar itself.

[Image of Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMmfu.png)

As you can see from the image link above, this causes problems with overlapping when the values for each location are similar. I'm looking for a solution to the overlapping.

Here is the code I'm using to impliment the chart (C# string appender for the google api javascript):

```
str.Append(@"<script type=*text/javascript*> google.load( *visualization*, *1*, {packages:[*corechart*, *bars*]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();            
    data.addColumn({type: 'string', label: 'Date'});
    data.addColumn({type: 'number', label: 'NC'});
    data.addColumn({type: 'number', label: 'WA'});
    data.addColumn({type: 'number', label: 'Std Cap'});
    data.addColumn({type: 'number', label: 'NC'});
    data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation', label: 'NCa' });
    data.addColumn({type: 'number', label: 'WA'});
    data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation', label: 'WAa' });
    data.addRows(" + dt.Rows.Count + ");");

for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    // Data values.
    str.Append("data.setValue(" + i + "," + 0 + "," + "'" + dt.Rows[i]["WeekNum"].ToString() + "');");
    str.Append("data.setValue(" + i + "," + 1 + "," + "'" + dt.Rows[i]["NC"].ToString() + "');");
    str.Append("data.setValue(" + i + "," + 2 + "," + "'" + dt.Rows[i]["WA"].ToString() + "');");
    str.Append("data.setValue(" + i + "," + 3 + "," + "'" + dt.Rows[i]["Std Cap"].ToString() + "');");
    // Invisible line to set annotations off of.
    str.Append("data.setValue(" + i + "," + 4 + "," + "'" + double.Parse(dt.Rows[i]["NC"].ToString()) + "');");
    // Annotation value; Multiply value by 100 to get percentage.
    str.Append("data.setValue(" + i + "," + 5 + "," + "'" + String.Format("{0}%", (100 * double.Parse(dt.Rows[i]["NC"].ToString()))) + "');");
    // Invisible line to set annotations off of.
    str.Append("data.setValue(" + i + "," + 6 + "," + "'" + double.Parse(dt.Rows[i]["WA"].ToString()) + "');");
    // Annotation value; Multiply value by 100 to get percentage.
    str.Append("data.setValue(" + i + "," + 7 + "," + "'" + String.Format("{0}%", (100 * double.Parse(dt.Rows[i]["WA"].ToString()))) + "');");
}

str.Append(" var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({ pattern:'#.#%' });");
str.Append(" formatter.format(data, 1);");
str.Append(" formatter.format(data, 2);");
str.Append(" var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div1'));");
str.Append(" chart.draw(data, {width: 1000, height: 600, title: '',");
str.Append(" stackSeries: true, isStacked: false, legend: {alignment: 'end'},");
str.Append(@" vAxes:{
    0: { 'maxValue': " + maxVal + @", format: '#%'},
    1: { 'maxValue': " + maxVal + @"},
    2: { 'maxValue': " + maxVal + @"}
    },");
str.Append(@" hAxis: {title: ''},
    seriesType: 'bars',
    series: {
        0: {type: 'bars', color: 'blue'}, 
        1: {type: 'bars', color: 'green'},
        2: {type: 'line', color: 'red', lineDashStyle: [4, 4]},
        3: {type: 'line', lineWidth: 0, visibleInLegend:false, pointSize: 0},
        4: {type: 'line', lineWidth: 0, visibleInLegend:false, pointSize: 0}                             
        },");
str.Append(@" annotations: {
    style: 'point',
    stemColor: 'none',
    textStyle: { color: 'black' },
                 alwaysOutside: 'true'                        
           }");
str.Append("}); }");
str.Append("<" + "/script>");

Literal lit = this.Master.FindControl("body").FindControl("lt1") as Literal;

lit.Text = str.ToString().Replace('*', '"');
```

The chart is populated by a dynamic table, named dt. Here's the layout of that table:

[Datatable Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AS3hq.png)

Chart drawing code (Javascript):

```
var options = { packages: ['corechart'], callback : drawChart};
google.load('visualization', '1', options);

function drawChart() { }
```

Chart Div on page (HTML/ASP.NET):

```
<div>                                        
    <asp:Literal ID="lt1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    <div id="chart_div1" style="width:1000px; height:600px"></div>
</div>
```

I'm not glued to the offset idea, this is just where I've landed from all my research. Ultimately I just want to display the percentages at the top of each column, so if there is a better way to go about that, I'm all ears!

Thank you in advance.

::EDIT::

After considering WhiteHat's comments below. I made the following adjustment to my for loop that does offset them (vertically) when the values are within 10 points of each other. This isn't the most elegant solution, but it does seem to work.

```
double ncVal;
double waVal;
double ncOffset;
double waOffset;

for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    ncOffset = 0;
    waOffset = 0;
    ncVal = double.Parse(dt.Rows[i]["NC"].ToString());
    waVal = double.Parse(dt.Rows[i]["WA"].ToString());

    // If values are within 10 points of each other, offset by 5 each positive/negative.
    if ((ncVal - waVal) < 0.10)
    {
        if ((ncVal - waVal) > 0)
        {
            if (ncVal < 1)
            {
                ncOffset = 0.03;
                waOffset = -0.03;
            }
            else
            {
                ncOffset = -0.03;
                waOffset = 0.03;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if ((waVal - ncVal) < 0.10)
        {
            if ((waVal - ncVal) > 0)
            {
                if (ncVal < 1)
                {
                    waOffset = 0.03;
                    ncOffset = -0.03;
                }
                else
                {
                    waOffset = -0.03;
                    ncOffset = 0.03;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Data values.
    str.Append("data.setValue(" + i + "," + 0 + "," + "'" + dt.Rows[i]["WeekNum"].ToString() + "');");
    str.Append("data.setValue(" + i + "," + 1 + "," + "'" + dt.Rows[i]["NC"].ToString() + "');");
    str.Append("data.setValue(" + i + "," + 2 + "," + "'" + dt.Rows[i]["WA"].ToString() + "');");
    str.Append("data.setValue(" + i + "," + 3 + "," + "'" + dt.Rows[i]["Std Cap"].ToString() + "');");
    // Invisible line to set annotations off of.
    str.Append("data.setValue(" + i + "," + 4 + "," + "'" + (ncVal + ncOffset) + "');");
    // Annotation value; Multiply value by 100 to get percentage.
    str.Append("data.setValue(" + i + "," + 5 + "," + "'" + String.Format("{0}%", (100 * ncVal)) + "');");
    // Invisible line to set annotations off of.
    str.Append("data.setValue(" + i + "," + 6 + "," + "'" + (waVal + waOffset) + "');");
    // Annotation value; Multiply value by 100 to get percentage.
    str.Append("data.setValue(" + i + "," + 7 + "," + "'" + String.Format("{0}%", (100 * waVal)) + "');");
}
```

Still, if anyone knows a way to center them on the columns, that would be ideal.

Comment: check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39771794/5090771), probably not exactly what you're looking for but could give you an idea...

Comment: @WhiteHat Thanks for your reply. I looked over the answer you provided. It's a good thought, I actually had tried something similar to that. I was offsetting the vertical alignment of the annotations to a set 'height'. In my case 100 and 110. It prevents them from overlapping, but my boss didn't like the result visually. So unfortunately, I have to keep looking for a a solution that prevents overlapping without a vertical offset.

Comment: @WhiteHat 

Even if I offset the data just by a small amount from the end of the bar, I would have to either detect what value the other annotation was and adjust the vertical offset to prevent overlapping as the data changes, or else manually adjust.

It's an idea, but I have no clue how to go about that.

Comment: _manual adjust_ is an option -- check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39854944/5090771) (see __EDIT__) -- it is concerned with the color of the annotation -- but shows how to find them and change attributes -- you could adjust the `'y'` attribute -- also, if the data is sorted the same as displayed on the chart, the annotations found in the dom should follow the order of the rows in the data...

Comment: @WhiteHat Thank you. I came to a similar realization after considering your comment. Rather that doing it the way you did in that linked answer, I just wrote some if statements to detect if the two values were within 10 points of each other and offset them a little if they were.

Unless I misunderstand that linked answer you were doing something similar by adjusting the 'y' attribute. It didn't seem like that would allow you to offset horizontally though, correct?

Comment: adjust the `'x'` attribute for horizontal...

Comment: @WhiteHat
It looks like you're using a tag to be able to reference that attribute. How do you assign that tag to something like an annotation? I'm not very versed in Javascript, so I'm struggling a little trying to adapt that linked answer as you suggested.