# How to draw vertical axis in google charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I am using gooogle charts. When I include constant values in the third & fourth column in my chart it shows me as horizontal lines. Please suggest how to draw it as vertical lines as shown in the image belows

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this,
Hereby a complete working fiddle to show you how it can be done:
 http://jsfiddle.net/NC37X/1345/

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

function drawVisualization() {
    // example copied from Google Visualization API playground,
    // modified for category axis annotations

    // Create and populate the data table.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'x');
    data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});
    data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotationText'});
    data.addColumn('number', 'Cats');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Blanket 1');
    data.addRow(["A", null, null, 1, 1, ]);
    data.addRow(["B", null, null, 2, 0.5]);
    data.addRow(["C", null, null, 4, 1]);
    data.addRow(["D", null, null, 8, 0.5]);
    data.addRow(["E", null, null, 7, 1]);
    data.addRow(["F", null, null, 7, 0.5]);
    data.addRow(["G", 'Foo', 'Foo annotation', 8, 1]);
    data.addRow(["H", null, null, 4, 0.5]);
    data.addRow(["I", null, null, 2, 1]);
    data.addRow(["J", null, null, 3.5, 0.5]);
    data.addRow(["K", 'Bar', 'Bar annotation', 3, 1]);
    data.addRow(["L", null, null, 3.5, 0.5]);
    data.addRow(["M", null, null, 1, 1]);
    data.addRow(["N", null, null, 1, 0.5]);

    // Create and draw the visualization.
    new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
    draw(data, {
        curveType: 'function',
        width: 500,
        height: 400,
        vAxis: {
            maxValue: 10
        },
        annotations: {
            style: 'line'
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked very well. Can we change the color of these lines

Comment: Colouring the lines: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39847740/different-colors-for-annotations-in-google-charts

Comment: Nope. I am trying on that post

Comment: This works.  `annotations: {
           style: 'line',
           stemColor: 'red'
        }` ,but All the lines same color

Comment: Yeah that seems the limitation here