# Show Value in Goole charts using Angular .TS

Tags: angular, charts, google-visualization

Am suing Google charts in Angular and am facing some difficulties when trying to apply the Google Documentation examples as am new to frontend and not familiar much with JS where in Angular am using TS.

My question is how to show the data values inside the charts, in google example its giving as

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
      view.setColumns([0, 1,
                       { calc: "stringify",
                         sourceColumn: 1,
                         type: "string",
                         role: "annotation" },
                       2]);
```

But as am using TS am not sure how to apply the same, I have tried so many things and checked multiple forms but all of them almost are using JS, what am currently deploying the chart as follows

```
.TS ==>

  Daigram1Type = "ColumnChart"
  chartColumns = ['Day', 'P3', 'P1',  'P3', 'P1', 'P3', 'P1'];
Diagram1Data = [
    
    ['Mon', 25, 11,5,27, 30,23],
    ['Tue', 20, 0,0,27, 30,23],
    ['Wed', 27, 30,1,27, 30,23],
    ['Thu', 30, 23,1,27, 30,23],
    ['Fri', 20, 20,1,27, 30,23],
    ['Sat', 7,10,0,0,0,0],
    ['Sun', 8,5,0,0,0,0],
  ];

Diagram1Options = { 
    legend: 'none', 
    isStacked:true,
    displayAnnotations: true,
    colors: ['green', '#cc0000', 'transparent', 'green', '#cc0000', 'transparent','green', '#cc0000', 'transparent'],
 };

HTML ==>

      <google-chart [type]="Daigram1Type" [data]="Diagram1Data" [options]= "Diagram1Options" [columns]="chartColumns"></google-chart>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the example you provided uses a data view to add the annotation column.
however, the annotations can be added directly to the data table instead.

you will need to add the annotation column role after each column heading for which the value should be displayed.

```
chartColumns = [
  'Day',
  'P3', {type: 'string', role: 'annotation'},
  'P1', {type: 'string', role: 'annotation'},
  'P3', {type: 'string', role: 'annotation'},
  'P1', {type: 'string', role: 'annotation'},
  'P3', {type: 'string', role: 'annotation'},
  'P1', {type: 'string', role: 'annotation'}
];
```

and the value to be displayed in the row data...

```
Diagram1Data = [    
  ['Mon', 25, '25', 11, '11', 5, '5', 27, '27', 30, '30', 23, '23'],
  ['Tue', 20, '20', 0, '0', 0, '0', 27, '27', 30, '30', 23, '23'],
  ...
];
```

Comment: Thanks that did the trick for me, one small question here do we have the flexibility to change the the annotations size, as when i did apply them now if the column (am using stacked) slice is very small the annotations value will be crossing the slice borders

Comment: yes, you can change the font size, as well as the length of the stem. you can do this for all the annotations, or you can set different sizes for each series individually. [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39854944/5090771)...